# Take the last column of a query and make the results comma separated in 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server (2018) Query where the last column (`SP.name`) can have multiple values , thus creating duplicate lines. I would like to take the results of that last column and drop all results into 1 field, comma separated.

For example, if the output of the query below is (you will see that one has Field Trip and the other birthday).

```
John , Smith, x@Z.com,New York, NY,  11208 , Field Trip
John , Smith, x@Z.com,New York, NY,  11208 , Birthday Party
```

I would like it to be like this , where Field Trip and Birthday are on the same column. note that it can be more than 2 results , some queries will have up to 5 results for that last column.

```
John , Smith, x@Z.com,New York, NY,  11208 , "Field Trip,Birthday Party"
```

This is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   CC.FirstName, CC.LastName, CC.Email, Addresses.City, Addresses.State, Addresses.Postal, SP.Name
FROM CustContacts AS CC WITH (NoLock) 
INNER JOIN Orders AS O WITH (Nolock) ON CC.CustContactID = O.ContactID 
INNER JOIN Customers AS C WITH (Nolock) ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN SalesPrograms AS SP WITH (NoLock) ON O.SalesProgramID = SP.SalesProgramID 
INNER JOIN OrderLines AS OL WITH (NoLock) ON O.OrderID = OL.OrderID 
INNER JOIN RMEvents AS RME WITH (NoLock) ON OL.EventID = RME.EventID 
INNER JOIN Addresses ON CC.AddressID = Addresses.AddressID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OEGroupVisits AS GV WITH (NoLock) ON O.GroupVisitID = GV.GroupVisitID
```

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to need all those joins.  Although they *might* be used for filtering, they don't seem to be doing much.

Because SQL Server 2016 doesn't support `STRING_AGG()`, you can use the `FOR XML` trick:

```
SELECT CC.FirstName, CC.LastName, CC.Email, a.City, a.State, a.Postal,
       STUFF( (SELECT CONCAT(', ', SP.Name)
               FROM Orders O JOIN
                    SalesPrograms SP 
                    ON O.SalesProgramID = SP.SalesProgramID 
               WHERE CC.CustContactID = O.ContactID 
               FOR XML PATH ('')
              ), 1, 2, '') as names
FROM CustContacts CC JOIN
     Addresses a
     ON CC.AddressID = a.AddressID ;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon ,  thank you that worked great ! . as for the joins, my select query has additional items that belong to those tables but i wanted to keep the select statement as simple as possible. thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a self join of the following tables: CustContacts, Addresses and SalesPrograms on some or all these columns: CC.FirstName, CC.LastName, CC.Email, Addresses.City, Addresses.State, Addresses.Postal, SP.Name.
Next, you will need to concatenate these 3 values: SP.Name, ', ', SP1.Name.   This is assuming you have SalesPrograms AS SP and SalesPrograms AS SP1 in your self join.